# Compass spriting

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

In order to achieve spriting by compass according to [the documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) I wrote this:

```
// web/sass/icons.scss
@import "../images/icons/*.jpg"; // for any cases also tried .png 
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

and got the error:

```
error sass/icons.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: ../images/icons/*.jpg.
```

I don't think the path is wrong because also tried full path.

The structure is like this:

```
+ web
  - sass
     + icons.scss
     + ...
  - images
     + icons
       - icon1.jpg
       - icon2.jpg
       - ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compass for sprites uses the paths defined in `config.rb`.

So if you have this structure:

```
+ web
  + sass
    - icons.scss
  + images
    + icons
      - icon1.png
  + config.rb
```

In your `config.rb` you should have something similar to this:

```
...
images_dir = "images"
sass_dir = "sass"
...
```

Then in your icons.scss you should do this:

```
// web/sass/icons.scss
@import "icons/*.png"; // for any cases also tried .png 
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

Because the import is relative to the `images` directory we defined above.

Be sure to understand the configuration file, because it may be tricky http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

Comment: thank you. it sounds reasonable. however, it doesn't work either: `File to import not found or unreadable: icons/*.jpg`. The interesting part is that for background images, for example, in scss files I use 'background: url(../images/somepic.png)' and it works

Comment: I didn't look at first at the icons you tried to import, but Compass supports only PNG for sprites. It's not written in the tutorial, but in the helpers section you can find that: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/

Comment: and also it should be `@include all-icons-sprites` :)

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo I tried your solution, but I have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809308/rake-assetsprecompile-bug-with-rails-and-compass-and

Answer (score 0):

this thread is quiet old but cool solution for spiriting with compass is here
[on github](https://github.com/paulgabronis/SCSS-Helpers)