# rake assets:precompile bug with rails and compass and "*"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, css-sprites, compass

I use rails 4.2.0 and compass-rails (2.0.2)

I have a css.scss file with

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites(true);
```

I have many image .png in app/assets/images/icons/XXX.png

I want deploy my app in production, it's work but with no assets, so I start

```
rake assets:precompile
```

in production environement.

An error occure:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'icons/*.png'
```

I try to remove assets files in cache, nothing change.

details error: http://pastebin.com/6ggS3pP2

I think there is a problem with wildcard and path.

I try in dev ENV, nothing change...

I don't know what do more, what's the solution, plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix it, I just use mster branch of git like :

```
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
```

Comment: compass-rails 2.0.3 was released earlier today, so now you can just include it as normal `~> 2.0.3`